# How exactly do the tracer pistols work?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I don't think I totally understand what the effects of the tracer pistol on a vehicle.

Does it provide auto-guidance to other weapons?
Which ones?

Does it just display the location of the vehicle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Darts can be fired either from the dart pistol or as secondary action by the Apache/Havoc gunner if he has alternative weapons package;
- Dart gun is the only weapon in BC2, which doesn't have any bullet drop at all. So don't aim above the target. Also even though it's almost silent, it will disclose your position as dart leaves red smoke trail;
- Once your target is marked with the dart, there will be voice notification for the whole team, also if you're close enough, you can see actually see it as little red light flashing;
- All of players on your team can take advantage of any dart placed by any team member;
- You get points if vehicle darted by you is damaged or destroyed by someone else;
- Darts work with RPG-7, Carl Gustav and Apache's Hellfire;
- Darts do NOT work with laser guided missiles: M136, stationary AT, UAV's Hellfire;
- You have to keep the dart indicator in the launcher sights to get lock-on. Direct line of sight is not required, you can get lock-on through wall, terrain etc. The indicator will turn solid and distance to target will be displayed when missile is locked-on;
- Missile guided by dart will fly straight in whatever direction you fire it for a second, then it'll fly straight towards dart. It will not avoid any obstacles in between. Thus the best tactic is to fire up towards the sky;
- When you're in vehicle hit by dart there will be beeping alarm and red flashing text "missile lock", can't miss it;
- Smoke-screen upgrade to vehicles removes any darts on them when used;

Comment: If you add a little info about how you need to keep the reticle on the target to achieve locked-on, and how you need to hit the target first with the pistol, I will select your answer.

Comment: yeah, added some info.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you have to do:

- Fire the dart at a vehicle (or a soldier, it's funny ;)
- Select one of the weapons using the darts guidance (RPG-7 AT, M2 Carl Gustav AT but not the M136, which is not compatible with darts)
- Find your taget and aim (you will see a yellow rectangle), then hit the magic multi-purpose `select` (on PS3, should be `Q` on PC). You will then see the live distance of the target, meaning it's acquired.
- You can now fire. It is better to aim high (sky for example) or a free area, so the missile will be able to maneuver to the target.
- BOOOM
- Enjoy your well earned points

You can of course be the one who fires the darts and the missile but it's not mandatory. You can sometimes see the flashing beacon on a vehicle and just aim, acquire and shoot.

Comment: The 'Q' part was what I didn't understand, thanks.

Comment: Hehe, it also took me a while to get this one. When you think there should be something more or "it would be cool if", just try to hit Q. It marks enemies, acquire targets, call for medic and ammo etc... It probably does even more!

Comment: Hm, I never tried pressing select button. If you aim at the red rectangle for couple seconds the distance would appear automatically.

Comment: You maybe right, I noticed a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *[Battlefield: Bad Company](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Tracer_Dart_Gun#Battlefield:_Bad_Company_2)* wiki the darts it fires can be locked on to by the RPG-7 and M2 Carl Gustav launchers, but not the AT-4.

Comment: Does that mean only those weapons 'heat seek' their target?  Also I noticed that you can see the vehicle markers even if you don't have those weapons equiped.  Does that mean it will work for other weapons?

Comment: Only those weapons will seek objects marked with tracer darts. The engineer class should only be able to see the "marked" identifier in the HUD, I'm honestly not sure if you need to have a compatible launcher in your loadout/actively equipped to see it or not though.